# Glue 3 divs together using css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 diferent divs and I want to "glue" them together. When I say glue them, I mean that I want to make one shape out of it. Here is my css and html code (with bootstrap):

```css
@keyframes fillin {
    0% {
        height: var(--beginHeight);
    }

    100% {
        height: var(--endHeight);
    }
}

.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper > div:before {
    background-color: blue;
}

#NadrzFrontView:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

#NadrzFrontView {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#NadrzDnoLevo:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzDnoLevo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px;
}

#NadrzDnoPravo:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzDnoPravo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0;
}

#NadrzLuby:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzLuby {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id="NadrzFrontView" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 wrapper">
        <div id="NadrzDnoLevo" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
        <div id="NadrzLuby" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
        <div id="NadrzDnoPravo" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does work pretty well, until I try it on mobile. Here is how it looks normally.[image]

My problem comes when I try it on mobile where it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, on mobile it looks horrible. I just want to somehow glue `NadrzDnoLevo`, `NadrzLuby` and `NadrzDnoPravo` together. Is it possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: why you don't do it with only one div?

Comment: I would love to do it using only one div, but I was unable to achive this shape and I need those lines seperating midlle part from 2 side parts. Also, I must be able to hide those 2 side parts with javascript then. So I am basically unable to do it in one div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of `float: left`, and you can use flexbox to make them stay side by side and not wrapping to the next line by adding these rules to the `.wrapper`:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Also, on top of that, you can add

```css
flex: 0 0 150px;
```

to `#NadrzDnoLevo` and `NadrzDnoPravo` and add

```css
flex: 0 1 500px;
```

to `#NadrzLuby` to make the capsule keep its shape.

```css
@keyframes fillin {
    0% {
        height: var(--beginHeight);
    }

    100% {
        height: var(--endHeight);
    }
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.wrapper > div:before {
    background-color: blue;
}

#NadrzFrontView:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

#NadrzFrontView {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#NadrzDnoLevo:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzDnoLevo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px;
}

#NadrzDnoPravo:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzDnoPravo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0;
}

#NadrzLuby:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzLuby {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    flex: 0 1 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id="NadrzFrontView" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 wrapper">
        <div id="NadrzDnoLevo" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
        <div id="NadrzLuby" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
        <div id="NadrzDnoPravo" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

one div solution to easy handle it:

```css
.box {
  --w: 50%; /* height of the blue coloration */
  --h:200px; /* Height of the element */
  
  height: var(--h);
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: var(--h);
  border: 3px solid;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) left  calc(var(--h)/2) top 0/3px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) right calc(var(--h)/2) top 0/3px 100%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom/100% var(--w);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s;
}
.box.hide {
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 
    center/calc(100% - var(--h)) 200% 
    padding-box border-box no-repeat;
  margin:20px calc(-1*var(--h)/2);
}

.box:hover {
  --w:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box hide"></div>
```

Comment: Nice and easy solution! Unfortunatelly I forgot to write that I then need to hide those 2 side parts (I am dumb).... Anyways thanks for the solution, I will use it on my other project where I dont have to do any JavaScript manipulation with shape :)

Comment: @AndrewBlack I also added the *hide part* in my answer. Adding a class will hide the side parts like I illustrate in my snippet

Comment: Oh sorry,.. It looks nice! Only thing is that: for Js manipulation I have to have it separated like 3 elements but thanks! I will use this in my other project because, it's less code and in my other project I dont need to have it (shape) seperated like 3 elements :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes fillin {
    0% {
        height: var(--beginHeight);
    }

    100% {
        height: var(--endHeight);
    }
}

.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper > div:before {
    background-color: blue;
}

#NadrzFrontView:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

#NadrzFrontView {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#NadrzLuby:before {
    --beginHeight: var(--startHeight);
    --endHeight: var(--finishHeight);
    animation: 3s fillin ease forwards;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 0;
}

#NadrzLuby {
    --var-height:300;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: calc(var(--var-height) * 0.5px);
    height: calc(var(--var-height) * 1px);
    width: 800px;
}
.line-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--var-height) * 0.5px);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 2.5px solid black;
}
.line-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: calc(var(--var-height) * 0.5px);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 2.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div id="NadrzFrontView" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 wrapper">
        <div id="NadrzLuby" style="--startHeight: 0%; --finishHeight: 50%">
            <span class="line-left"></span>
            <span class="line-right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```